# How many min & max values to remove?

Tags: repeated-measures, mean, outliers, median

I imaging that the following problem is quite common, so there should be recommendations what to do.

I've got multiple measurements of a certain value. Let's order these measurements:

```
X1 < X2 < ... < Xn
```

I'd like to deduce the value `X` in a stable manner. One way to do that is to compute mean:

```
X_mean = (X1 + ... + Xn) / n
```

Unfortunately, mean is very sensitive to outliers. Thus taking the median becomes an attractive alternative:

```
X_median = X(n/2)
```

Yet another is to discard min & max values and compute the mean of the remaining values:

```
X_less2 = (X2 + ... + X(n-1)) / (n-2)
```

One can imagine other intermediate solutions:

```
X_less4 = (X3 + ... + X(n-2)) / (n-4)
```

Thus the question: how does one determine what approach is optimal, given particular data, in evaluating the measured value in a manner stable against outliers?

I looked at Chauvenet's criterion for outliers, but I don't think it applies here because I'd like to remove a few min & max values in pairs.

Comment: I think there is not right answer for that broad question. If you want just to estimate the center, look at the histogram and see if the median is ok. If not, some trimmed mean would be better. If you are on a regression setting maybe some winzorization would work.

Comment: You haven't explained why you are carrying out these calculations. What is their purpose? With respect to this purpose, how would you determine whether one approach is better than another?  (You need to do this in a quantitative way in order to make any sense of "optimal" in the question.) Finally, please note that the solution will likely depend not on the data themselves, but rather on the assumptions you make about those data.

Comment: @whuber: here is the setup. We are trying to deduce how width of lines after removal of resist changes from the exposure width. We perform multiple measurements, and, because measuring width of thin lines in the resist is inaccurate, we get high variability. Thus we need to prune some measurement result. For example, if get measurements 90, 92, 95, 96, 120 than 120 is clearly an outlier. Should we reject 120 or both 90 and 120? Should we take an average of 92, 95, 96 or the median 95?